# The sandbox is not syncing with podfile.lock in ionic Version 6

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, cocoapods, ionic4

I'm trying to build my ionic project in ios and, I'm getting the following error for days.

[image]

I have already install cocopods and pod by running

`sudo gem install cocopods` in my root directory and `pod install` in my platforms/ios

Can someone please kindly help me.

Comment: try `pod update`

Comment: Hi @PaulBeusterien, I already tried that also. Still having the same issue